# Users getting set as Guest and Registered when using Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions

My Users are Still getting set to Guest regardless of me setting their roles as Registered once registered. I'm really wondering why? Below is an image

[image]

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
include SessionsHelper
before_filter { |c| Authorization.current_user = c.current_user }



 helper :all
  protect_from_forgery


  protected

  def permission_denied
    flash[:error] = "Sorry, you are not allowed to access that page."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**User Controller**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
     @user = User.new(user_params)
     @user.role == ["registered"]
    if @user.save

        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        log_in @user
        redirect_to @user
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :username, :id, :role)
    end
end
```

**USER MODEL**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :roles, :through => :interviews, :source => :user
before_create :set_default_role
 ROLES = %w[ admin creator registered guest ]

  def role_symbols
    roles.map do |role|
      role.name.underscore.to_sym
    end
  end
private
  def set_default_role
    self.role = 'registered'
  end
end
```

**Authorization rules**

```
authorization do 
    role :admin do 
        has_permission_on [:interviews, :exhibitions, :posts, :comments, :abouts, :products, :available_works], :to => [:index, :new, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    end

    role :creator do
        has_permission_on :interviews, :to => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
        has_permission_on :comments, :to => [:edit, :update, :create, :destroy]
    end

    role :guest do
        has_permission_on [:interviews, :exhibitions, :posts, :abouts, :products, :available_works, :home], :to => [:index, :show]
        has_permission_on [:users], :to => [:new, :show, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy, :index]
    end

    role :registered do
        has_permission_on [:interviews, :exhibitions, :posts, :abouts, :products, :available_works, :home], :to => [:index, :show]
        has_permission_on [:sessions, :users], :to => [:new, :show, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy, :index]
        has_permission_on :comments, :to => [:edit, :update, :create]
    end  
end
```

**Interview Controller**

```
class InterviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_interview, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  filter_resource_access

  # GET /interviews
  # GET /interviews.json
  def index
     if params[:tag]
      @interviews = Interview.all.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
     @interviews = Interview.all
    end
  end

  # GET /interviews/1
  # GET /interviews/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /interviews/new
  def new
    @interview = Interview.new
  end

  # GET /interviews/1/edit
  def edit
  @interview = Interview.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /interviews
  # POST /interviews.json
  def create
    @interview = Interview.new(interview_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @interview.save
        format.html { redirect_to @interview, notice: 'Interview was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @interview }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @interview.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /interviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /interviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @interview.update(interview_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @interview, notice: 'Interview was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @interview }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @interview.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /interviews/1
  # DELETE /interviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @interview.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to interviews_url, notice: 'Interview was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_interview
      @interview = Interview.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def interview_params
      params.require(:interview).permit(:title, :description, :tags, :image, :taggings, :tag_list)
    end
end
```

Comment: Try changing `@user.role == ["registered"]` to `@user.role == "registered"`

Comment: Why not add a Role model (pun not intended)?